# Running docker image for ASP.NET core sample from Microsoft on arch linux, cant browse to http://localhost:5000

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, archlinux

I installed arch linux (current version archlinux-2024.03.01-x86_64) on VM VirtualBox 7.0 (didn't use the archinstall script in case thats' relevant)

Install docker and git with

```
pacman -S docker
pacman -S git
```

And run the `pacman -Sy` and `pacman -Su` commands

Then followed the steps from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I cloned the docker dotnet app with

```
git clone https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker
```

Built it as per instructions

```
docker build -t aspnetapp .
```

And got it to run (not sure why didn't run first try but eventually ran)

```
docker run -it --rm -p 5000:8080 --name aspnetcore_sample aspnetapp
```

This the output after executing the docker run command:

[image]

I can see from tty2 (other terminal) the container is running with `docker ps` command

[image]

However can't do a wget to the localhost:5000 or use lynx
[image]

What am I'm missing to set up  to browser the url/webapp ?

note: I have network/internet in the arch virtual machine but haven't configured anything else

**Update / Solved**
I executed the run command with a typo `5000:8000` instead of `... 5000:8080` (thanks [Exploding Kitten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743754/exploding-kitten) for spotting the typo looks like my eyes aren't that sharp anymore)

Once I re-ran the command properly I can lynx to http://localhost:5000 url

[image]

Alternatively running from the repo also works as mentioned by [jdchris100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12695057/jdchris100)

```
docker run -it --rm -p 5000:8080 --name aspnetcore_sample mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run it directly from their docker repo

`docker run -it --rm -p 5000:8080 --name aspnetcore_sample mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp`

can you visit http://localhost:5000/ ?

Comment: Because you have a typo in your command, in the post you provided `-p 5000:8080` which is correct, but the screenshot has `-p 5000:8000`.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten oh you're right now I'm getting page not found error 404

Comment: @JDChris100 let me try that.

Comment: my bad again I tried now lynx http://localhost:5000/app instead of http://localhost:5000

Now it's working ! thank you @ExplodingKitten

Comment: @JDChris100 this also works ! thank you didn't know you can do that.